# Syslog-ng with mysql destination - increase log retention

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, syslog-ng

I have this dusty `syslog-ng 3.1.3` that writes to a database and all is working well however it seems to keep only 30 days of logs (last table is `logs20150826`) 
How can I increase that? I see nothing immediately clear in the documentation.

There are some references in logrotate dirs but nothing that seems to be controlling the mysql destination and nothing in `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf` so this 30 day retention must be some kind of default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have php-syslog-ng installed, syslog-ng isn't responsible for this.

> Log rotation
>
> Log rotation should be part of most installations where you use
>   php-syslog-ng. It is better to use log rotation than deleting rows in
>   the main table because deleting rows can lead to performance problems.
>   Rotating old logs out of the main table will also usually result in
>   better performance because the tables with old logs are static and can
>   be optimized. There is a logrotate.php script in the scripts
>   directory. You may have to edit it to enter the correct path to your
>   php-syslog-ng installation but after that it should be ready for use.
>   If you enable merge tables in the config.php file then a merge table
>   of all log tables will be created at the end of the script. The merge
>   table will allow you to search across all tables instead of having to
>   do searches against one table at a time. The merge table does equate
>   to a slight performance hit on the search form because the fields are
>   populated based on all tables instead of one particular table.
>
> You can also specify enable the LOGRETENTION setting in config.php. If
>   you enable this then logs older than this setting will be dropped
>   whenever the logrotate.php is run.
>
> If you decide to use the logrotate.php script then just add it to your
>   crontab and have it run however frequent you want (max is currently
>   one time per day).

Source http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/syslog-ng.htm

Comment: ..So logrotate goes on mysql every day and creates a new log table for syslog-ng to insert into? I certainly cant find anything that does that in `/etc/logrotate.d` or `/etc/logrotate.conf`

Comment: sorry I didn't read the entire question, syslog-ng does not do rotation/cleanup so it would be a 3rd party utility.

Comment: Yep! there was a setting in `/var/www/php-syslog-ng/html/config/config.php` with `define('LOGROTATERETENTION', 30);`

Comment: Also If you haven't tried it yet, graylog is awesome!

Comment: Heh ok, and yes that thing definitely needs attention (=scrap and replace with something modern that is hah)

Comment: You'll get he retention you want without the degradation of performance, plus you can do streaming and alerts to hipchat/pagerduty/email and that's just awesome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29535/discussion-between-jacob-evans-and-recct).